# Connect the rasa project built with rasa version 1.10.6 to the latest rasa x version (0.35.x) using the integrated version control feature of rasa x

Tags: chatbot, rasa, rasa-x, nlu

I developed my chatbot project with rasa 1.10.6 before rasa released rasa 2.0. I would like to know if I can add my old rasa 1.xx project with the current rasa-x version (0.35.x) or with future rasa-x versions, as I don't want to use an old rasa-x version that had bugs with the integrated version control feature. (Because I hope that the latest rasa-x project had fewer bugs when working with the integrated version control feature.)